# Local module code update in apache airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have following folder structure in Airflow dag folder.

```
/opt/airflow/dags
--my_module/
--my_dag.py
```

Dag file(my_dag.py) need python scripts inside my_module to do the workflow tasks.

Above setup run perfectly but when update a python script inside "my_module" folder it doesn't reflect in the workflow.

When change the dag file it'll reflect the changes in the airflow. I have restarted airflow also but no luck. What I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting both Airflow Webserver and Scheduler